# Remove ".NET" from AppIcon

Tags: maui

I have a .NET MAUI App with an AppIcon which should be displayed as it is.
Unfortunately, I can see a white-colored ".NET" logo inside this AppIcon.

How can I get rid of that?

=========== Added Icon to see the wrong effect =================

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android

Comment: You may try remove the ```ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg"``` part in MauiIcon section in  csproj file. Clean and rebuild the project

Comment: I would also like to mark your comment as Answer because the key for me was removing ```ForegroundFile=...``` completely form the ```MauiIcon``` section in my csproj - Good Job and thank you very much for your help

Comment: So glad you solved it. And yes, the appiconfg.svg foreground file is the one which draws .NET logo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this article about [how to change the App icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=android#change-the-icon). You can define the App icon by yourself.

Here is the code below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I added a screenshot so that it can be seen what I mean. The white ".NET" Logo is integrated from .NET MAUI itself and is not in the original image

Comment: How did you change this appicon? You can check this [Platform-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?tabs=macios#tabpanel_1_macios) to change the icon for the IOS platform.

Comment: I did not change anything, it was done automatically and that’s why I came up with my question. I just replaced the existing AppIcon-file in Resource-Subfolder with my ne AppIcon, which was named as the existing one (AppIcon), which then was a simple replace of the existing AppIcon

Comment: You can check the link I provided in the comment. Does it will happen if you change it for the iOS platform?

Comment: As mentioned in comment of @Liqun Shen-MSFT above the key for me was to remove the ```ForegroundFile=``` from the ```<MauiIcon ...``` section so that it looks like in this Answer - Great job @Guangyu Bai - MSFT and thank for your help

Answer (score 2):

First go to the Assets folder in your .NET MAUI project because this folder contains icon assets for different platforms and resolutions.

Find the icon file corresponding to the platform you are targeting. For iOS, look for the AppIcon.appiconset folder. For Android, check the drawable or mipmap folders.

Replace the default icon files with your custom icon files. Make sure your custom icons have the correct dimensions and resolutions specified in the platform's guidelines.

Build and deploy your app to see the updated icon. The white ".NET" logo should no longer appear, and your custom icon will be displayed instead.

Remember to adhere to the platform-specific guidelines for icon dimensions and resolutions to ensure your icons look good on various devices and screen densities.

Alternatively, if you are using Visual Studio, you can modify the app icon through the project properties:

Right-click on your .NET MAUI project in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties."

In the project properties window, navigate to the "Application" tab.

Under the "Application" tab, find the "Icon" section. Click the "..." button next to the "Icon" field to open the icon selection dialog.

In the dialog, browse and select your custom icon file.

Click "OK" to save the changes.

Ensure that your custom icon file meets the recommended dimensions and resolutions for each platform.

Comment: What is the Assets-Folder? Unfortunately, I don't have one with this name. Also, the way that was described via Properties did not work, as there is no Icon field below the Application tab

Comment: I added a screenshot so that it is more clear how it looks like. I want to get rid of the white .NET Logo inside. It is not in the original image.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" from .csproj, it was still showing .NET written on icon.

So just cleaning and building the solution worked for me.